# What is an xml dom namespace and why do some DOM methods have NS at their end?

Tags: javascript, dom, namespaces, xml-namespaces

why do I need to write it? and why do some methods of DOM have NS at their end, what's the purpose of such methods?

Comment: does the [wikipedia article on XML namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) ([which is easy to find](https://www.google.cz/search?q=what%20is%20xml%20namespace)) resolve your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespaces are meant to resolve `<tagname>` conflicts

Consider this XML tree:

```
<aaa xmlns="http://my.org">
    <bbb xmlns="http://your.org">hello</bbb>
    <bbb>hello</bbb>
</aaa>
```

the first `<bbb>` tag belongs to the namespace `http://my.org`

the other one belongs to the namespace `http://your.org`

---

Another example

```
<company xmlns="http://someschema.org/company"
xmlns:chairman="http://someschema.org/chairman">
    <nameValue>Microsoft</nameValue>
    <chairman:nameValue>Bill Gates</chairman:nameValue>
    <countryValue>USA</countryValue>
</company>
```

There you can see two `<nameValue>` tags, one is the **company's name**,
one refers to the **chairman's name**... but that conflict is resolved using a prefix!

Another way to write that is:

```
<com:company
xmlns:com="http://someschema.org/company"
xmlns:cha="http://someschema.org/chairman">
    <com:nameValue>       Microsoft    </com:nameValue>
    <cha:nameValue>       Bill Gates   </cha:nameValue>
    <com:countryValue>    USA          </com:countryValue>
</com:company>
```

So, if you don't specify a prefix, you are defining the default namespace

```
xmlns="http://default-namespace.org"
xmlns:nondefault="http://non-default-namespace.org"
```

Means, for example, that a descendant element `<sometest>` belongs to `http://default-namespace.org`

`<nondefault:anotherone>` instead belongs to `http://non-default-namespace.org`

---

Why using URLs as a namespace string? because they identify a certified source with no risks of conflicts (a domain name can be only owned by one single person)
so the URL you put in the `xmlns` attribute isn't downloaded or parsed somehow, it's just a string that uniquely identifies your tags namespace.
You could use, at the same way, for example a string such as `xmlns="com.yourcompany.yournamespace"`

---

So, DOM methods such as **document.getElementByTagNameNS()** are meant to select elements of a specific namespace

```
<?php

// asking php some help here
// page must be served as application/xml otherwise
// getElementsByTagNameNS will not work !!!

header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8");

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <com:company
        xmlns:com="http://someschema.org/company"
        xmlns:cha="http://someschema.org/chairman">
        <p>this is html!</p>
        <com:nameValue>       Microsoft    </com:nameValue>
        <cha:nameValue>       Bill Gates   </cha:nameValue>
        <com:countryValue>    USA          </com:countryValue>
        <p>this is html!</p>
    </com:company>

    <script>
        //<![CDATA[

        window.onload = function(){

        alert("html paragraphs: " + document.getElementsByTagNameNS(
        "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "p").length);

        // selects both <com:name> and <cha:name>
        alert("any nameValue: " + document.getElementsByTagName(
        "nameValue").length);

        // selects only <com:name>
        alert("company nameValue: " + document.getElementsByTagNameNS(
        "http://someschema.org/company", "nameValue").length);

        // selects only <cha:name>
        alert("chairman nameValue: " + document.getElementsByTagNameNS(
        "http://someschema.org/chairman", "nameValue").length);

        };

        //]]>
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I would like to ask if there is  a `document.getElementByIdNS()` to get the element by id

Comment: there's no getElementById equivalent for xml atm, but have look at this http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/ and that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/xml/xml:id